# Making a Rails relationship with a custom name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a model called company and one called user, and User belongs to Company and Company has many Users.

But I want to store on the company model the master company admin user, but I want to do it with a custom name.

So, i want to do this: comapany.owner.name .

How can I do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your Company needs one additional field

```
owner_id :integer
```

then add to Company

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
```

Comment: I just can't believe how simple rails is. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem. You can just choose an answer when you are done :)